# Create MongoDB new collection with json inside the schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I try to create new collection with mongodb.
I wrote the MongoDB shcema, Nodejs+express code and everything work fine until I send parameters with Json inside them.

I was created this schema (and also more code under this schema) but its not work and I got error:

```
const partySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    datetime: { type: Date, required: true },
    location: {
        scraping_location: { type: String, required: true },
        display_location: { type: String, required: false },
        city: { type: String, required: false },
        adress: { type: String, required: false },
        area: { type: String, required: false }
    },
    picture: { type: String, required: true },
    url: { type: String, required: true },
    affiliate_url: { type: String, required: true },
    music_by: {type: [], required: false },
    music_type: {type: [], required: false },
    min_age_for_men: {type: Number, required: true },
    min_age_for_women: {type: Number, required: true },
    status_check: {type: Boolean, default: false },
    tags: {
        concept: { type: String, required: false },
        free_text: { type: [], required: false }
    },
    producer_id: { type: String, required: false },
    
});
```

and the code that I wrote with nodejs+express is this:

```
const { title, datetime, location, picture, url, affiliate_url, music_by, music_type, min_age_for_men, min_age_for_women, tags, producer_id } = req.body;

const party = new Party({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    title,
    datetime,
    location: { scarping_location: location.location_scarping },
    picture,
    url,
    affiliate_url, 
    music_by,
    music_type,
    min_age_for_men,
    min_age_for_women,
    tags,
    producer_id
});

party.save().then(() => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Create a new user'
    })
}).catch(error => {
    res.status(500).json({
        error
    })
});
```

when I send reqeust to the api with this body:

```
{
    "title": "test",
    "datetime": "2002-07-15T10:00:00+0300",
    "location": {
        "location_scarping": "new york"
    },
    "picture": "test.jpg",
    "url": "https://google.com",
    "affiliate_url": "https://google.com",
    "min_age_for_men": 18,
    "min_age_for_women": 16
}
```

I got this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": {
            "location.scraping_location": {
                "name": "ValidatorError",
                "message": "Path `location.scraping_location` is required.",
                "properties": {
                    "message": "Path `location.scraping_location` is required.",
                    "type": "required",
                    "path": "location.scraping_location"
                },
                "kind": "required",
                "path": "location.scraping_location"
            }
        },
        "_message": "Party validation failed",
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "Party validation failed: location.scraping_location: Path `location.scraping_location` is required."
    }
}
```

why its happend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is just a typo, from your schema:

> `scraping_location: { type: String, required: true }`

You're trying to insert: `location_scarping` not `location_scraping`

> `"location_scarping": "new york"`

Hopefully that fixes it.